# Totient number for which the smallest element of the inverse is even?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Suppose , $k$ is a positive integer and there exists a positive integer $n$ with $\varphi(n)=k$

> - Can the smallest value $n$ with $\varphi(n)=k$ be even ?
> - Can all values $n$ with $\varphi(n)=k$ be even ?

I did not find a counterexample even for the first statement upto $3\cdot 10^4$. It is clear that the smallest value $n$ cannot be of the form $4m+2$ because then $\frac{n}{2}$ would also be a possible value.

The given statement is a strengthening of the conjecture that there is no $k$ such there is exactly one $n$ with $\varphi(n)=k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [OEIS sequence A002181](https://oeis.org/A002181). The answers to both questions are yes. For example  $\varphi(n)=16842752$ only for even $n$.